Escape and Fn keys not working on 2017 MacBook Pro with touch bar
The escape key on the touch bar of my 2017 MacBook Pro stops working periodically. F1 - F12 which seem messed up too but escape is what I originally noticed. They even light up when I press them but nothing happens. So I know the physical touch is being registered. The other things like volume, back in browser, etc. all seem to be working fine.
A restart fixes the problem, but it has come back a few times and I'd like to not have to restart every time it happens.
I can test this in Vim. Control + [ works for sending escape to Vim as a workaround. This website does not show escape being pressed (nor the function keys). I thought that site might be hiding those key presses but after a restart when the keys are working again I can see them registering as pressed on that site.
